Convexity and existence of an unique or interval optimal portfolio
Consider a basic static portfolio choice problem with two assets. An investor chooses a portfolio, which is to allocate positive fractions of her fixed wealth into the two financial assets. Financial assets are random variables that take values within the range of (a,b).
Now suppose I define convexity as follows: If an investor prefers asset 1 to asset 2, then the investor prefers a portfolio of asset 1 and asset 2 (this creates another asset, and let's name it asset 3) to asset 2. Since asset 3 is preferred to asset 2, then a portfolio of asset 3 and asset 2 is also preferred to asset 2...
My question is whether this assumption of convexity means the existence of a unique or an interval-optimal portfolio. Optimal portfolio simply means there is a portfolio that is preferred to any other portfolio. My intuition tells me so, but I could not find any references. If anyone could explain this in detail and provide some references, that would be much appreciated.

Please tell us what you mean by "best."  Greatest expected rate of return? Greatest chance of a positive return?  Greatest risk-adjusted expected rate of return?  Etc.  Then, please provide more detail about your "convexity" assumption: in particular, what does it mean when there are more than two assets?

You also need to assume transitivity of preferences. That, plus the finiteness of the number of assets and your other assumptions, leads to the existence of an optimal solution, as it implies that the elements of the portfolio can be ranked—in which case the optimum portfolio has 100% allocated to the preferred asset.  Without transitivity of preferences, you can have $A \succ B \succ C \succ A$, and no unique optimum.

Hi, my question has become more clearer. Actually, I only have two assets to start with. The convexity is about the relation between the resulting portfolio of the two assets. I have changed my question. Can you please comment again?

Emma: When you say "prefer", you would need to specify that the preference is because the expected return is greater or the variance of the return is less ? There are two aspects of "goodness" of a portfolio so prefer is not specific enough. Why is asset 1 preferred over asset 2. For example, If there are only two assets and asset 1 has a greater mean return and less variance and no covariance with asset 2, then asset 1 will ALWAYS be TOTALLY preferred to asset 2. They would never be held as a portfolio with weights $w_1$ and $w_2$.

@mlofton My assumptions are imposed on the binary preference relations, and these then can lead to implications for the underlying preferences. The invesetor could prefer asset 1 to asset 2 for whatever decision rule she has. If we know that the investor has mean variance preferences, then yes, her preferences depend on the tradeoff of mean and variance, but in my setup the underlying preferences are unknown.

Hi Emma: Oh okay. It definitely sounds more complicated than regular mean variance. I don't know if binary preferences imply something about an optimal portfolio ? But I'm not even certain what optimal would mean. Hopefully someone else can say something helpful. I can't.
